# Unity Optimization: Is disabling Animator is more performant?

Tags: unity-game-engine, optimization

While in idle states, is disabling Animator have any impact on performance?

Comment: I would claim anything you disable is saving some performance yes, question is if it is that much of an impact .. couldn't you try this yourself using the profiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled animators are better than empty idle state looping animators in the 500-1000 animator range.
Between 100-200 animators the effect is negligable.

Answer (score 0):

Trying this out in-editor, there's no difference performance-wise about an idle animator and a disabled animator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).